# How to specify programmatically which resource to use in .xcassets

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, xcode6, assets

If I am using code to load an Asset resource in Xcode, how would I go about specifying which resource to use? To break this down, suppose I have an image named `bgImage` and I have the @1x, @2x, R4, and @3x versions of the image in the Asset Catalog. I understand that by default, the compiler will choose to load the hardware-specific image (i.e. the @2x on an iPhone 4s, the @3x on the iPhone 6 plus), but how would I go about using a different image than set by default? For example, suppose `bgImage` loads as a @2x image but i would like it to load as a R4. What would be the code to do this?

I am using SpriteKit, and have tried using

`SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bgImage-568@2x"]`, but this returns a big red X.

If I use

`SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bgImage"]`

then it loads the @2x, not the R4.

Help please!

Comment: add the image with a different name

Comment: I was hoping there would be another way in case apple rolls out another iphone screen and app will no longer work

Comment: in case that happens (and it will) it's our job to update your app accordingly and timely. You cannot preemptively work around that because you can only rely on the builtin mechanisms to behave sensibly on the new device, but any workaround aka custom hack is more than likely to screw things up on the new devices.

Comment: True, our support team is fast, and should there be any issues we would be working on the fix right away; however, user satisfaction is priority in many cases and we attempt to, as you call it, preemptively apply workarounds to potential bugs. Thanks though!